# I have trouble creating constant variables through user input in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
int getX()
{
    int temp_x;
    cin >> temp_x;
    
    return temp_x;
}

int main()
{
    const int x = getX();
    double arr[x];
    ...
}
```

```
int temp_x;
cin >> temp_x;
const int x = temp_x;
double arr[x];
```

I tried using this code, but neither of these solutions worked. Visual studio keeps showing messages about how the constant variable 'x' cannot be defined like this.
The only time I got these messages to go away was when I defined 'x' with an integer literal.

When I used Visual Studio Code with MinGW compiler, I never had these types of problems. In fact, I didn't even have to use constant variables; I could use normal integer variables and simply not change them!

Comment: The array bound doesn't merely have to be a constant - it has to be a **compile-time** constant. A dynamically sized array is spelled `std::vector` in C++.

Comment: Variable-length arrays are not standard C++. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: So if I want to choose how many values I want my array to have, I should use a vector instead?

Comment: Yes, that's the best solution.

Comment: `std::vector<double> arr(x);` would be similar to what you expected `double arr[x];` to do.

Comment: Just because some random IDE doe not show you warnings does *not* mean that there's no problem. Your IDE is *not* authoritative, your actual compiler is. Compile your code, see what the compiler says - don't rely on what your IDE says.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I found the solution to my problem!

Comment: @Rism_m you can write down your self-answer in the answer section.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could write down your self-answer and mark it as answer. Because this will be beneficial to other community.